# SQL Server Parameter "Not Supplied" - but it Is

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Consider this code....
WHY is it failing telling me that the @PI_CDID parameter value is not set when trying to execute the stored procedure?

```
Console.WriteLine("Database Opened!");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("P_IOU_Track", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PI_CDID", ICDID)); // parameter is added here
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PI_Title", ITitle));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PI_Duration", IDuration));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PI_CDNo", ICDNo));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PI_TNo", ITNo));
foreach (SqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parameter , {0} , Value --> {1} ",p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
}
// Add output param
SqlParameter NextTID = new SqlParameter("@PO_NextTID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
NextTID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(NextTID);
// Execute procedure
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You might get this message if the *value* you're providing is actually `NULL`

Comment: Don't you need to set the type of the SqlCommand? SP vs text?

Comment: it's text by default. Is your conn open? conn.open()

Comment: What gets written to the `Console` for each of your parameters?

Comment: Try adding `conn.open()` before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and add `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` after you initialize `cmd`

Comment: Also, if your `P_IOU_Track` proc in turn calls other procs then the error could be coming from further down the call chain.

Comment: Show your stored proc definition.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`